# Move an HTML element up exactly 1 line-height

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have some markup:

```
<dl><dt>1</dt><dd>One</dd><dt>2</dt><dd>Two</dd><dt>3</dt><dd>Three</dd></dl>
```

Which I would like to style such that the `<dd>`s are in-line with the `<dt>`s. My document's `line-height` is set to `1.3`. Knowing that `em`s are equal to the `font-size` and that `line-height` is a percentage of the `font-size`, I tried:

```
body { line-height: 1.3; font-size: 75%; }
dd { margin-top: -1.3em; margin-left: 10em; }
```

Giving the `<dt>`s a reasonable spacing for my data. This did not work, as in pixels the `line-height` measured `15px` but `1.3em` measures `15.6px`. According to http://www.brunildo.org/test/line-height-approx.html, different browsers compute the exact pixel value of a line-height differently - I was developing in Chrome, and was lucky to be caught by it.

For the purposes of this question I would like to avoid pixels - specifying `line-height`, and `margin-top` in pixels would work, but would resize poorly.

Here is a uri which shows the problem:

```
data:text/html,<style>body { line-height: 1.3; font-size: 75%; } dd { margin-top: -1.3em; margin-left: 1em; }</style><dl><dt>1</dt><dd>One</dd><dt>2</dt><dd>Two</dd><dt>3</dt><dd>Three</dd></dl>
```

Comment: The last bit - that isn't a URL.  That is a bunch of markup code.

Comment: Try pasting it in the url bar of Chrome or Firefox (without NoScript)

Comment: Just becaue you can put in in your browser doesn't make it a URL, at least I don't think it does.

Comment: @AJMansfield you're right - it is a URI, not a URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme.

Comment: @AJMansfield: it's a perfectly valid (and working) URI

Comment: @michaelc then you should have sair URI not URL, because that is U+006C after the u and r, not U+0069.  Doesn't really matter though, nobody really cares what you call it as long as the understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of what you want to achieve, you want each dt/dd pair on the same line?

Here is a working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/w9YQx/1/

Use floats, and clear. line-height, font-size etc is irrelevant.

```
dt {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
}
dd {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
​
```

You can set the widths to whatever you want, this is just an example

Answer (score 1):

`<ol>` seems to be a better fit in this case, but you can do something like this:

```
dl {
    font: 200%/1.3 Arial;
    overflow: hidden;
}

dt {
    clear: both;
}

dt, dd {
   float: left;
   margin-left: 0.5em;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgBvV/1/

Comment: I was just using the numbers as metasyntax - in my case its labels and data.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: relative;
bottom: 1.3em; /* same as line height */
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FjbTb/1/)

Comment: Andre, this still displays the same error in Chrome, though I can see where you wanted to go with it. It appears that Chrome is rounding down the value, however it calculates it.

Comment: @michaelc: Hum, ok, now I see what the problem really is. You should take Mark's approach, then.